# Why findAncestorWidgetOfExactType is O(N) and dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType is O(1)

Tags: performance, flutter, dart, documentation, inherited-widget

in Flutter there are two functions :

- **findAncestorWidgetOfExactType**
- **dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType**

in the docs they say that: *findAncestorWidgetOfExactType* is relatively expensive (**O(N)** in the depth of the tree).

and *dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType* is **O(1)** with a small constant factor.

anyone can explain why ? why the first one is more expensive than the other ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the question and understand why there is a difference in time complexity between the two methods, we first need to clarify two things:

**1- What is Linear Searching ?**

> Linear search (known as sequential search) is an algorithm for finding
>   a target value within a list. It sequentially checks each element of
>   the list for the target value until a match is found or until all the
>   elements have been searched.

And in short, O(1) means that it takes a constant time, (for example 10 nanoseconds).

on the other hand O(N) means it takes an amount of time linear with the size of the set, so a set twice the size will take twice the time. You probably don't want to put a million objects into one of these.

hence the hint in the docs of  *( findAncestorWidgetOfExactType )*

> "Only call this method if the distance from this widget to the desired
>   ancestor is known to be small and bounded."

**2- What is the Generic 'Type' each method searches for and *Where* ?**

- dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType< T extends **InheritedWidget** >
- findAncestorWidgetOfExactType< T extends **Widget** >

with these in mind we can answer the question  ..
so Why ?

Because the findAncestorWidgetOfExactType method is searching in all the widget tree ( cause they are all of type **Widget** by default )

and this is done by **linear searching** up the widgets tree thus comes => O(N).

> This part is updated thanks to **Mabsten** answer

on the other hand dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType
searches **Not** in the widget tree but instead in a **map** that comes with every Element containing all ancestor **InheritedWidgets**, indexed by their **type**.

So 'dependOn' - **directly** - fetches the right inherited widget from this map that's why it is O(1).

Answer (score 6):

The main difference for performances is not due to the fact that `findAncestorWidgetOfExactType()` searches for any Widget subclass, while `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType()` searches only for InheritedWidget subclass.

`dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType()` is less expensive because every widget (more precisely, every Element) keeps a Map (in the field `_inheritedWidgets`) of all ancestor InheritedWidgets, indexed by their type. Then `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType()` doesn't search in the widget's tree, but only in this map.

Useful articles:

["How does Flutter InheritedWidget work?"](https://medium.com/manabie/how-does-flutter-inheritedwidget-work-3123f9d74c15)

["Widget - State - Context - InheritedWidget"](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/06/widget-state-context-inheritedwidget/) (of Didier Boelens, an article's author cited also in flutter.dev)

Comment: Thanks alot , that  'dependOn' part wasn't very clear to me, the medium article clarified everything Thanks again.

So, the 'findAncestor' does linear searching for a widget type that matches the given type in the widgets tree that's why it is O(N) , and the 'dependOn' - directly - fetches the right widget from the map ( in each element )  with the given type as a 'key' that is why it is O(1).